# Triggering different actions on same route based on request type in Zend Framework 2

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, zend-framework2

I am trying to make ZF2 respond in REST way to different request type.

In my module.config.php I have this router config.

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'student' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(

                'route'    => '/student[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),

                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Student\Controller\Student',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

On frontend I am using Backbone to send GET, POST, DELETE requests to server based on user interactions.
When user trigger action to delete student with id of n, backbone will send /somePath/student/n using DELETE request.
When user trigger action to get student with id of n, backbone will send /somePath/student/n using GET request.

If I want current setup to work I have to change Backbone request and change URL from student/n to student/delete/n if I want to delete student with that id and similarly for GET.

This is what I did on client side which I would like to avoid.

```
define(['backbone'], function(Backbone){
    return Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            //set default model values
        },
        initialize: function(){
            //initialize
        },
        methodToURL: {
            'delete': '/student/delete'
        },
        sync: function(method, model, options) {
            options = options || {};
            var id = arguments[1]['id']
            options.url = model.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()] + '/' + id;
            return Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    });
});
```

In controller on server side I have different action methods I would like to run for different request types.

```
public function deleteAction()
{
        //some code
}
public function getAction()
{
        //some code
}
```

I don't want to change default backbone behaviour (intercepting and altering requests).

Is there a way to configure ZF2 router to use same route but trigger different actions based on request method type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Method` route as child route of segment route. http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html

There is a example named `A complex example with child routes` where author for `blog` literal route create child routes each of which is different type.

Simply You can create child routes in your student route which will be type `Method` for each method You want to use and then change only action for this method types.

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'student' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(

                'route'    => '/student[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),

                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Student\Controller\Student',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'delete' => array(
                    'type' => 'method',
                    'options' => array(
                        'verb' => 'delete',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'delete'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                'put' => array(
                    'type' => 'method',
                    'options' => array(
                        'verb' => 'put',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'put'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),//and so on...
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Although I ended up using AbstractRestulController suggested by Otto Sandström I will accept your answer because I asked how to make changes to router only and you provided the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Mvc.Controller.AbstractRestfulController.html)

It will call Certain function depending on the HTTP request method

```
class StudentRest extends AbstractRestfulController {

    /** 
     * will be called with a GET request when it detects that route
     * matches paramater id has been set
     */
    public function get($id) {
        /*load studentdata*/
        return new JsonModel($data);
    }

    /**
     * Will be called on a POST request, and data should be sent with a $_POST
     * This should create a new object/row in db and return 201
     */
   public function Create($data) {
       /*create student*/
       $this->response->setStatusCode(201); // if new student was created.
       return JsonModel();
   }

    /**
     * Will be called on a PUT request. Data should be sent via $_POST
     * It also requires that the $id parameter is set in the route match
     */
   public function Update($id, $data) {}

    /**
     * Will be called on a DELETE request, It requires that the $id parameter is set in the route match
     */
   public function Delete($id) {}
}
```

with that u can just link to the controller via the route as so

```
'student' => array(
        'type'    => 'segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/student[/:id]',
            'constraints' => array(
                'id'     => '[0-9]+',
            ),
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Student\Controller\StudentRest ',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

there are also some function for getList which will be called when not suppling $id in route parameters.
Also might be worth saying that the default implementation of all the functions returns a 405 with a ['content' => 'Method Not Allowed']

[Documentation how to use it](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.controllers.html#the-abstractrestfulcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation :
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.request.html

**Determining the Request Method**

getMethod() allows you to determine the HTTP request method used to request the current resource. Additionally, a variety of methods exist that allow you to get boolean responses when asking if a specific type of request has been made:

```
isGet()

isPost()

isPut()

isDelete()

isHead()

isOptions()
```

The primary use case for these is for creating RESTful MVC architectures.